# During the whole life of Nand Flash, Is read a safe operation?

Tags: filesystems, embedded, flash-memory

On today's interview, i have been asked a interesting question

"During the whole life of Nand Flash, Is read a safe operation?"

We all know that erase or write will cause bad block. But is read operation safe? for example, if i put some data into nand flash, and never change it after.I just read it over and over again, will there be some problems?Also i'm told that this have no relation to ECC

Comment: It is highly dependant on the technology.  It is best to use a file system that assumes they will wear.  Everything eventually wears out. MLC flash is typically read-disturb, but SLC doesn't have this specific problem.  Every floating gate will eventually discharge.  Many parts guarantee higher reliability for the first/boot blocks.  It **IS** related to ECC; if a read bit flips, the ECC catches it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, read operations can cause *read disturb* problems. Search for "nand flash read disturb" on Google for example, it will give plenty of articles on the matter, for example [this at Micron](http://www.micron.com/~/media/Documents/Products/Presentation/flash_mem_summit_jcooke_inconvenient_truths_nand.pdf), or [this at SanDisk](http://www.sandisk.com/assets/docs/wp001_flash_management_final_final.pdf).

Comment: Interesting we were causing read disturb in some spi flash parts, I dont remember it being permanent though (fixed by an erase cycle as these say), it was temporary as we stressed a location/bank and went away when we recovered from the crash (rebooted) which did not involve a write cycle.  As a rule we do not run (much) code from the flash any more, just enough to cache a copy loop (linear code execution, linear reads) which does one read pass on the program copies to ram jumps to ram, done with flash, read disturb problem solved.

Comment: note links are discouraged at stackoverflow, this answer loses its value if either of those links change or the content goes away, if you can include enough of a description in your answer on SO then this answer will not die when the links die.  (google will probably be around for a long time and hopefully the googling part of your answer will work).

Comment: @dwelch: The problem is that I just don't know about this subject, just working in embedded, have some experience on how to search and find answers, and to know when I am on the right track finding those. So I say I am simply not qualified to write a better answer here :)

Comment: ... aaand, I just Googled this answer and both links are dead. :) There goes the knowledge I wanted to learn.